# Extracting maximum value(with nearby values) in ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to extract maximum value with some boundaries in ndarray(numpy).

For instance, there is ndarray N which size is (30000,1000), and I want to extract maximum value with some boundaries( (index of max value)-100 ~ (index of max value)+100 ) for each row.

So I wrote code like this

```
for item in N:
  item = item(item.argmax()-100 : item.argmax()+100)
```

but after doing this task, I get still (30000,1000) for N.shape

If I want to (30000,200) for the N.shape value, what code should I have to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you do not always get 200 values around the maximum. Imagine your maximum in one row is the second value, then you will only get 102 values. So casting it back into a numpy array will anyways not work.

My suggestion, create a new list and append each item to the list, that is,

```
# Import
import numpy as np

# Random data
N=np.random.random((30000,1000))

# List for new results
Nnew=[]

# Loop
for item in N:
    item = item[max([0,item.argmax()-100]) : item.argmax()+100]
    Nnew.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your method and changed Nnew to ndarray and saved to N.
I mean, N=np.asarray(Nnew)
However, I converted (25000,1000), (10000,1000), (5000,1000) this kind of ndarray by iterating same method 3 times, but strange thing is, 
it results (25000,),(10000,200),(5000,200) each.

Comment: but converting (2000,1000), (10000,1000), (5000,1000) results (2000,1000),(10000,200),(5000,) like this. is this normal? or are there any method to get desired result - (25000,200),(10000,200),(5000,200) ?

Comment: The problem is that if you want to convert a list into an ``ndarray``, every element in the list needs to have the same lengths (for instance 200). As already mentioned in my answer, this is not always the case. If at least one element doesn't fulfill this requirement, numpy will convert it into a 1d array of lists.

Do you need to have ``N`` to be an ``ndarray``?

Comment: I've noticed my fault, so I decreased window length. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on the answer from @alexblae. For the list you need to consider edge cases, since arr[-3, 4] == [], in most cases. You could also use numpy arrays, by moving your selection to fit within the row, if it is close to the edge:

```
import numpy as np

a = 30000  # number of rows
b = 1000   # number of items in a row
c = 100    # number of items to pick
N = np.random.random((a, b))

# create a list of values close to the max
# lists varies in size if close to an edge
Nnew = []
for row in N:
    idx_max = row.argmax()
    # avoid indexes out of range
    idx0 = max(0, idx_max - c)
    idx1 = min(len(row) - 1, idx_max + c)
    Nnew.append(row[idx0:idx1])

# create an array of items close to the max
# moves "window" if close to an edge to pick enough items
Nnewer = np.zeros((a, 2 * c))
for i, row in enumerate(N):
    idx_max = row.argmax()
    # avoid indexes out of range
    if idx_max < c:
        idx_max = c
    elif idx_max + c >= b:
        idx_max = b - 1 - c
    Nnewer[i, :] = row[idx_max - c : idx_max + c]
```

Of course, there are many ways to deal with edge cases, this is just one suggestion.